# Reseting navigation in React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

[This is snack in official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset) but its not working. On reseting stack in snack, if I press go back, it goes back to previous screen.
When I open app from notifications it goes to notification screen. But if I navigate to home screen and reload app programmaticaly it shows notification screen on loading. How to prevent that? I'm using `react-navigation/native` V6.

Comment: reload app programtically ? how?

Comment: using [react-native-restart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart)